# JMeter: How to send HTTP GET request using BeanShell

Tags: http, jmeter, request, jmeter-5.0

I am studying JMeter and want to make a HTTP GET request to http://google.com using BeanShell Sampler without using HTTP Request Sampler. Is it possible? And if so, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible however I fail to see why would you need this.

Moreover [starting from JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting mainly because Groovy has much better performance comparing to Beanshell, in addition Groovy is more modern language which supports all the latest Java features and provides [a lot of enhancements](https://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html) on top of it, see [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details.

Example code:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://google.com");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
SampleResult.setResponseData(EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity()));
```

More information:

- [HttpClient Quick Start](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/quickstart.html)
- [HttpClient Tutorial](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/tutorial/html/index.html)